# Show that $ \operatorname{Sp}(n)=\{A \in M_n(\mathbb{H}) \mid AA^*=I=A^*A\} $ is a compact group

Tags: general-topology, matrices, algebraic-topology, compactness, topological-groups

Let $M_n(\mathbb{H})$ be the set of all $n \times n$ matrices with entries in the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$.

For $A=(a_{ij} ) $ let $ A^*=(a^*_{ij} ) $ be the matrix with $a^*_{ij}=\bar{a}_{ij}  $, where $ \bar{x} $ denotes the quaternion conjugate of $x \in \mathbb{H} $. Let:

$$ \operatorname{Sp}(n)=\{A \in M_n(\mathbb{H})\mid AA^*=I=A^*A\} $$

> Show that $ \operatorname{Sp}(n) $ is a compact topological group

A compact topological space if one such that any open cover $\bigcup_\alpha \cup_\alpha$ of $X$ has a finite subcover $\bigcup_{i=1, \ldots, n} U_{\alpha_i}$ where finitely many indices $\alpha_i$ are from the same index set $A$

Also the Heine Borel criterion states that a space is compact if it is closed and bounded.

I also note that there is no determinant function $M_n(\mathbb{H}) \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$, so how else can we show this

Comment: The inverse-image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed.  The function $A\mapsto A^* A$ is continuous.  The underlying set of this group is the inverse image of the singleton set $\{I\}$, so it is closed. $\qquad$

Comment: Note that Heine–Borel applies to subsets of Euclidean space, not to topological spaces, or even metric spaces, in general.  For example, the closed unit ball in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is closed and bounded but not compact.  However, in the situation you contemplate, the Heine–Borel theorem can be applied. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks. So is it to show that a topological group is closed to show compactness? Or something else too

Comment: You still need to show boundedness. And "closed" in this case means closed when embedded in a larger space, and in order to apply the Heine–Borel theorem, that larger space has to be Euclidean space. $\qquad$